# Does the contains() method in Java ArrayList use binary search?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, binary-search

Does the contains() method in Java ArrayList use binary search? Or do I need to use Collections to do this instead?

Comment: you know Java is _open-source_, you can check the code of _contains()_ method, huh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you need to use `Collections` to use binary search, usually after sorting it.  An `ArrayList` doesn't know anything about its ordering, and you have to know a list is sorted before you can use binary search.

Alternately, you could use `TreeSet`, which is as efficient as using a binary search.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't use binary search as lists don't have to be sorted.

Use the utility methods of the Collections class to first sort the list and then to perform a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would mean adding a overhead at each insertion so it's not included.

Here's the source code : it just tests all values :

```
218     public boolean contains(Object o) {
219         return indexOf(o) >= 0;
220     }

229     public int indexOf(Object o) {
230         if (o == null) {
231             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
232                 if (elementData[i]==null)
233                     return i;
234         } else {
235             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
236                 if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
237                     return i;
238         }
239         return -1;
240     }
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you need to use Collections to use binary search, usually after sorting it.